# how do I configure my asp.net project to use WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, wcf

I am new to WCF. I have asp.net project which was normal 3tire project. The structure of my solution is like
1. DAL (class library Data Access Layer project)
2. BL (class library Business Logic)
3. BO (Business Object class library)
4. TestOnline (main web project client)
5. WCFServices (Class library project)
 Now I want to include WCF class library project into same solution and use WCF service to learn. I created proper service and contract. My web.config file for main web project is modified as below

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="dbConnect" connectionString="Data Source=WIN-3150RFE75I8\PMSSERVER;Initial Catalog=TestDb_OnlineExam;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=pmsadmin1!" />    
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  <authentication mode="Forms">        
 </authentication>     
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"></serviceHostingEnvironment>
<services>
  <service name="WCFServices.LoginWcfService" behaviorConfiguration="LoginWcfServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFServices.ILoginWcfService" behaviorConfiguration="web">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
  </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="LoginWcfServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <serviceDiscovery></serviceDiscovery>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
</protocolMapping>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

When I try running my project the error message displayed is :

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'LoginServiceReference.ILoginWcfService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

I am unable to find out anything about this error.

I checked running my WCF service and it runs fine. Just not able to use it in my web project. What attributes do I need to add/modify to make things work.

Comment: Is that correct that you have single visual studio solution that contains WCF project and ASP.Net project along with DAL, Business Layer projects? If so, the first think I would do is keep the WCF project including all dependent projects into a saperate VS solution. This way you can host your WCF in a console based application for debugging purpose. Secondly, your config file doesnt have any contract entry for "LoginServiceReference.ILoginWcfService" Have you posted all the contents of web.config file?

Comment: @YawarMurtaza It is not necessary to put all the WCF projects in _"another solution"_ just for console-based debugging or otherwise

Comment: @MickyD thats correct and I never said it is necessary. Since the OP is new to WCF it make sense to keep things saperate and that helps it to be organised and transparent. Little things like this really help when learning new tehcnologies :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I suggest start up your wcf site. When it is running, review the assigned port. After that, go ahead adding it like client in the web config of your main web. The following page can be useful:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/client-configuration